# Save value in a database field based on the entry of the user name which was saved

Tags: symfony, doctrine, fosuserbundle, symfony-sonata, sonata-admin

I installed the sonata-admin, sonata-user and forsuser on my symphony2 installation (2.1.2)
Everything works fine. I can create a user and can also login into it.

Then I added to my Entity/User class one additional field, which should be filled by a method which needs the entered username as import. (License Field).

My Problem now is, that I don't know how to do this. I created also my own userAdmin class to create the form.

But everything I try I have no clue or find out how to implement the mentioned aspect.
The idea would be that the user is entered in the form and after the button create user a method should be called which get's the username and returns the value which should be stored in the database.

Can somebody helo me out and give me some hints to identify where I have to change something, where I have to store my method hand how to call this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't fully understand your problem but looks like you could use Sonata's [saving hooks](http://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/saving_hooks.html) to solve it.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for. Bur I don't know how to use this. I added a function public function postPersist($User) {}. But how can I know call another function were one of my database fields (from the user entity) will be updated based on the entered username.

Do I have to add my function (createLicense) to the useradmin class? How do I call this function?

Comment: I tried to add the following function to my useradmin:

`code`    public function postPersist($user)
    {
     $user2 = $user->setCbsoftwarekey("Hallo");
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
     $em->persist($user2);
 
    }

But this is not working.

Comment: Inject dependent services into your UserAdmin service just like in the FOSUserBundle example in the link I gave you.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Do you know if there is probably another example  because for me the link you send is not so clear. BR

Comment: There's really no simpler way of explaining it. In the example UserManager is injected into UserAdmin service. You should do the same with all the services you need inside the UserAdmin service.

Comment: Sorry. I tried for more than two weeks to solve this issue. But I didn't come along. My Problem is that I don't know how to inject the function into the UserAdmin. The only think what I ant is that when I create a user another db field will be filled in addition with a value based on the username which was saved. Is there really no other explanation or help on that. I can't believe that nothing could be found on the internet and nobody has done this before.

Comment: You could also use doctrine or symfony event listeners.

Comment: Oh thanks a lot. The hint with doctrine event listener helped me and now I solved the issue after twi weeks of try and error. It was only some line of code. (<lifecycle-callbacks>
            <lifecycle-callback type="prePersist" method="setLicense"/>
        </lifecycle-callbacks>) In my ORM Model. And that's it. Thanks